# Docker context not changing (docker context use)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using the command `docker context use` in order to set the active Docker context:

```
> docker context use aws-context
aws-context
```

However, the active Docker context does not change for some reason.

When I subsequently type `docker context show`, the activated context is still the default context:

```
> docker context show
default
```

When I list the existing contexts, the asterisk is still behind the default context:

```
> docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                              DOCKER ENDPOINT             
aws-context         ecs                 (eu-west-1)                                                                  
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration  tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

How can I change the Docker context?

Comment: Is the remote cluster reachable form your machine?

Comment: Yes, it's an AWS service and I can ping the AWS container registry.

Comment: Is there any _verbose_ option for the `docker context` command? In order to get some more output? Unfortunately, I did not find any.

Comment: Yes, I can see it is ECS. I think that ECR does not play a role here. It looks to me that your endpoint is not working and that's why docker won't let you select that context, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set, it will always take precedence over the newer `docker context use` workflow.

Type `env | grep DOCKER` in your shell to see if you have any docker-specific variables set. unset them by typing `unset DOCKER_HOST`. Other variables such as `DOCKER_CONTEXT` may also get in the way.

The `docker context use` command should work fine once that variable is out of the way.

This is noted in the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/#the-anatomy-of-a-context):

> The easiest way to see what a context looks like is to view the default context.
>
> ```
> $ docker context ls
> NAME          DESCRIPTION     DOCKER ENDPOINT              KUBERNETES ENDPOINT      ORCHESTRATOR
> default *     Current...      unix:///var/run/docker.sock                           swarm
> ```
>
> This
> shows a single context called “default”. It’s configured to talk to a
> Swarm cluster through the local `/var/run/docker.sock` Unix socket. It
> has no Kubernetes endpoint configured.
>
> The asterisk in the `NAME` column indicates that this is the active
> context. This means all `docker` commands will be executed against the
> “default” context **unless overridden with environment variables such as
> `DOCKER_HOST` and `DOCKER_CONTEXT`**, or on the command-line with the
> `--context` and `--host` flags.

(bold added by me)

Comment: Good hint, thank you very much! I had an environment variable `DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME` which was set to `default`.

Comment: Did not work for me. No DOCKER variables at all and also "docker context show" and "docker context ls" were showing different default contexts. What helped was to change context few times.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced problems with env variable: `DOCKER_CONTEXT`. 
Make sure that you are setting it correctly...

instead of:

```
pb@L1:~$ DOCKER_CONTEXT=example
pb@L1:~$ echo $DOCKER_CONTEXT
example
```

use:

```
pb@L1:~$ export DOCKER_CONTEXT=example
pb@L1:~$ echo $DOCKER_CONTEXT 
example
```

alternatively (if you are using docker extension in VSCode, modify settings.json) 
**ctrl+shift+p -> Open workspace settings (JSON)**

```
{
    "docker.context":"remote_workstation"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the docker context to `default` worked for me.

```
docker context use default
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).